# Use Delphi5 in Delphi XE environment

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe, delphi-5

Is it possible to compile a Delphi5 project in the new XE IDE without any migration?

If've been using Delphi5 IDE for quite a while now and, to be honest, it is old, unfriendly and unflexible. I tried out XE and was impressed, however I am not interested in migrating projects to newer versions of Delphi.

So, is it possible? And if not, are there other IDEs that support Delphi5 in that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not - Delphi XE is unicode-only. And there are no other IDEs. As for Delphi 5 - that was a great version and we widely use it until now. Try looking for some add-ons and experts for Delphi 5 that make development more comfortable. CodeRush, ModelMaker Explorer are commercial ones, and there were some free addons. Personally I use ModelMaker Explorer for Delphi 5, which I purchased years ago.

Answer (score 2):

In our case it took around 4-5 weeks to migrate our project from D7 to D2010. There are some good links where you can see what kind of code should be modified and think if it worth it in your case, the main difference is the Unicode-issue.

For example, any code that manipulates or does pointer operations on strings should be examined for Unicode compatibility. More specifically, any code that:

- Assumes that SizeOf(Char) is 1
- Assumes that the Length of a string is equal to the number of bytes in
  the string
- Writes or reads strings from some persistent storage or uses a string
  as a data buffer

Take a look at the [complete article from Embarcadero](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38693)

Comment: If they are anything like us they will have different projects with different levels of activity. The most active ones they will want to migrate and the ones which are very rarely changed may as well stay with D5.

Comment: They might also use third party libraries that are not easy to upgrade (or in the worst case binary-only) which prevents upgrading.

Comment: @David: Right. We had one big app and some small tools beside, the EXE's beside were no problem but the big app was a real piece of work. Besides we had problems writing/reading the Data over BDE, so we decided to move from BDE too. Having all at once was'nt really comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy XE, you're entitled to older versions of the IDE as well (back to D7, IIRC). Delphi 2007 is almost as good an IDE as XE, and it will compile D5 code as long as you have the source with only minor changes. (Typically, having to add Variants to the uses clause is the major issue.)

Answer (score 1):

Andreas Hausladen has a Delphi plugin that offers this sort of functionality (compile in an IDE using a different version of dcc32 than native to that IDE).  It's called [IDE Compiler Plugin](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-compiler-plugin-10/).

However, it's only available Delphi 2007 and 2009.  To be frank I think you are better keeping both versions of Delphi installed side by side.

Comment: I think as soon as you open an old project in XE, all form data will be converted to Unicode.

Comment: @FractalizeR Is that something new in XE. All my D2010 .dfm files are ANSI.

Comment: Converting back from Unicode to ANSI would be possible using a simple tool that opens all dfm files and saves them as ANSI.

Comment: On second thought you'd have to copy all files to a separate directory to achieve compiling with the D5 compiler and editing with XE.